# Realm Update Deleting existing data

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Using Swift 5 for iOS13.

I am trying to update an existing Realm record with a Contact Picker result.  The function deletes all the object content except for the new content.

My code

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var personId = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var surname: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var mobileNumber: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var password: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var myContactID: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "personId"
    }
}

extension HomeController: CNContactPickerDelegate {
  func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let person = Person()
    let me = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("mobileNumber == %@", mobileNumber)
    person.myContactID = contact.identifier
    person.personId = me.first!.personId
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(person, update: .modified)
    }
    self.viewWillAppear(true)
  }
}
```

All the existing content of the Person class in the Realm database disappears except for myContactID and personID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are updating the `Person` with new data. 
The line `let person = Person()` creates a new instance with all the default values. (`firstName: String = ""` etc..)

So, when you assign `myContactID` and `personId` to this newly created `person`, it will look like this:

```
Person {
    personId = FAE4C224-D37E-4C77-B6F1-C60A92F188D0;
    firstName = ;
    surname = ;
    mobileNumber = ;
    password = ;
    myContactID = contactIdentifier;
}
```

And when you call `realm.add(person, update: .modified)`, it will overwrite the record associated with the primary key with this newly created `person`.

You want to fetch an existing `person` and modify it. You can do something like this:

```swift
guard let me = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("mobileNumber == %@", mobileNumber).first else { return }
try! realm.write {
    me.myContactID = contact.identifier
}
```

Comment: I get an app crash with error:  dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _$s10RealmSwift0A0V5write16withoutNotifying_xSaySo20RLMNotificationTokenCG_xyKXEtKlF @kentaro

Comment: @Glenn try clean the build folder and rebuild.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.

Comment: @Glenn While on the surface this answer appears correct, it may not be the whole answer. You don't need to retrieve the user to then update it; as long as you know the primary key of the user, you *can* create a new person object, like this 'let person = Person()', populate it's primary key with the persons primary key you want to update, add any values you want to change and then `realm.add(person, update: .modified)' and it will update that object directly without overwriting it. That being said, you would need to know the primary key. Other than that, this is a solid answer with an upvote.

Comment: @Jay; i don't know the primary key hence the query to retrieve it.  The cache clear works for running the app on the simulator, but I get a library fail error for IQKeyboard when testing on my phone... >:(

Comment: @Glenn Ah.. If you don't know the persons id then that's more of a design issue. You may want to re-think that as if you are selecting a person in a collection view or tableView, you should also have access to their id in code, which makes updating that persons properties a snap, a lot less code and no queries.